# C# Dynamically apply evaluation rule on a collection

Tags: c#

I have a fixed-length data file need to persistence into database. I use a XML file to define the length for the fields and use a list of FieldItem class to store the data.

```
   class FieldItem
   {
        public string ObjectName {get; set;}
        public string ObjectProperty {get; set;}
        public string ObjectValue {get; set;}

        public FieldItem()
       {
       }
   }
```

So the FieldItem will look like

```
var fieldItem = new FieldItem
                {
                   ObjectName = "Company",
                   ObjectProperty = "Name",
                   ObjectValue = "ABC Corp."
                }
```

After get the list of FieldItem, I will do refection to create Company and other domain objects to save them into database.

But before they are saved into database, I have some business rules needed to be applied to validate the data line. My data line will look like:

```
var fieldItemList = new List<FieldItem>(){
                new FieldItem {
                    ObjectName="Company",
                    ObjectProperty = "Name",
                    ObjectValue = "ABC"
                }

                new FieldItem{
                    ObjectName = "Product",
                    ObjectProperty = "ProductCode",
                    ObjectValue ="XYZ0123"

                    new FieldItem{
                    ObjectName = "Product",
                    ObjectProperty = "ProductName",
                    ObjectValue ="Christmas Tree"       
                }

                    // other FieldItem objects...

            }
```

For example, my rule is to check if the company == "ABC" and ProductCode == "XYZ0123". Those rules are created by users and stored as a string in the database. What I am doing right now is to use Microsoft's System.Linq.Dynamic to evaluate the rule, such as

```
string validationRule = " (ObjectName == \"Company\" And ObjectProperty=\"CompanyName\" And ObjectValue = \"ABC Corp.\") And (ObjectName == \"Product\" And ObjectProperty=\"ProductCode\" And ObjectValue = \"XYZ0123\") ";

  var query = fieldItemList.AsQuerable().Where(validationRule);
```

then check if it has one row return to tell if that data row has passed the rule or not.
Obviously, it is too verbose. Do you have any better suggestion? What should I do if I only like my rule expression like: "Company.CompanyName = 'ABC Corp.' and Product.ProductCode = 'XYZ001'"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RE: "What should I do if I only like my rule expression like: "Company.CompanyName = 'ABC Corp' and Product.ProductCode = 'XYZ001'"?

Map this user-friendly query: "Company.CompanyName = 'ABC Corp' **AND** Product.ProductCode = 'XYZ001'" to something that is friendly to your data structure(FieldItem):

"ObjectName = 'Company' AND ObjectProperty = 'CompanyName' AND ObjectValue = 'ABC Corp' **OR** ObjectName = 'Product' AND ObjectProperty = 'ProductCode' AND ObjectValue = 'XYZ001'"

How to know if the user's rules passed the rules or not? Count the number of conditions, if it matches the count of results of fieldItemList.AsQueryable().Where(itemFieldFriendlyQuery), then the data line is valid based on user's rules.

---

some rudimentary mapper(use regular expression or roll your own parser to make the following code truly valid):

```
public Form3()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string userFriendlyQuery = "Company.CompanyName = 'ABC Corp' AND Product.ProductCode = 'XYZ001'";

    string[] queryConditions = userFriendlyQuery.Split(new string[]{" AND "},StringSplitOptions.None);
    int conditionsCount = queryConditions.Length;

    string itemFieldFriendlyQuery = string.Join(" OR ", 
        queryConditions.Select(condition =>
            {
                var conditionA = condition.Split(new string[] { " = " }, StringSplitOptions.None);

                var left = conditionA[0];
                var leftA = left.Split('.');

                string objectName = leftA[0];
                string objectProperty = leftA[1];

                var right = conditionA[1];

                return string.Format("ObjectName = '{0}' AND ObjectProperty = '{1}' AND ObjectValue = {2}",
                    objectName, objectProperty, right);
            }
        ).ToArray());



    MessageBox.Show(itemFieldFriendlyQuery);

    // outputs: "ObjectName = 'Company' AND ObjectProperty = 'CompanyName' AND ObjectValue = 'ABC Corp' OR ObjectName = 'Product' AND ObjectProperty = 'ProductCode' AND ObjectValue = 'XYZ001'"


    bool isValid = fieldItemList.AsQueryable().Where(itemFieldFriendlyQuery).Count() == conditionsCount;


    MessageBox.Show(isValid.ToString());
}
```

Comment: That is a great approach! Do you think it is easy to take more complicate comparison? such as "(A == 1 (B == 2 OR C == 3))". I am considering to create another class to store FieldItem,to create the property as Company_Name,so I can take Company_Name == "ABC" in dynamic LINQ where clause

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [FileHelpers](http://www.filehelpers.com) library to parse your file directly into regular .NET domain objects. I believe this, combined with your Dynamic Linq approach, will provide you with the syntax that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could have them store it in the database as C# code expression, and then use the CodeDom classes to parse and compile it into a type which exposes a method which will run the comparison.

That will create a lot of temp assemblies, which would be a PITA to manage, IMO.

Rather, I'd still use the C# notation for expression syntax, but instead of compiling it into code, create a lambda expression dynamically (through the Expression class) and then compile into a delegate that takes all the parameters (you will need a mapping mechanism here) and then just call it using your created types.

Answer (score 0):

For your `FieldItem` class, couldn't you create a property where you can inject a Predicate delegate method, such that:

```
class FieldItem
{
    public string ObjectName {get; set;}
    public string ObjectProperty {get; set;}
    public string ObjectValue {get; set;}
    public Predicate<FieldItem> EvalMethod { private get; set; }

    public FieldItem()
    {
    }

    public bool Evaluate()
    {
        return EvalMethod(this);
    }
}
```

For constructing your `FieldItem` object then, you could use the following:

```
new FieldItem { ObjectName = "SomeObject",
                ObjectProperty = "SomeProperty",
                ObjectValue = "SomeValue",
                EvalMethod = GetEvalMethodFor("SomeObject")
               }
```

Of course you will have to have a parser of some sort (`GetEvalMethodFor` method above) to translate your validationRule string into a boolean evaluation method.

In your collection, you can then call the `Evaluate()` within, say, a `foreach` loop.

**UPDATE**

If you need to evaluate each and every object in the list, you can do this:

```
bool areAllItemsValid = true;

foreach (var f in fieldItemList)
{
    areAllItemsValid = areAllItemsValid && f.Evaluate();

    if (areAllItemsValid)
    {
        continue;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

return true;
```

You can opt to inherit `List<FieldItem>` and make an `EvaluateAll()` method to contain the above, or declare it as a method in a separate object altogether.

Comment: Thank you, Jon! But I need to evaluate the list of FieldItem, instead of a single one. Put another way, we have a list of FieldItem objects, I need to verify some of them to make sure it passes the validation rules.

Comment: Thanks again Jon! Sorry, it is my fault, I should make my question clearer. Actually I need a more complicate validation rule, such as (A == 1 And (B == 2 OR C == 3) And (D == 4)). I guess dynamic linq is the way to go, but I need to construct my class correctly to make it work with dynamic linq.

Comment: Liang, In that case I'm starting to think using a type-ignorant FieldItem object may be the wrong direction to go, and it might be better to go with specific object structures. For what you describe, it is obvious that a List<T> is the *wrong* representation for the object that you wish to represent

Comment: You are correct. FieldItem is a only temp class to store the data from the data line. You see, ObjectName/Property/Value, I am going to do reflection to generate real domain objects to persistent them.Those rules are changed very often. They are created by users from a UI.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside: why class instead of struct?

Value types for data, reference types for behaviour.

Comment: Is that relevant? You should've posted this in the comments instead.

Comment: I did try, but Stack Overflow won't let me add a comment because I don't have enough "Reputation"

"commenting requires 50 reputation -- see faq"

Comment: After reading the faq, the funny thing is by voting me down you (potentially) made it even harder for me to add a comment instead of an answer :)

Comment: That description is incorrect; this is a mutable POCO - it should *absolutely, 100%* be a class. It is *very very rare* that you need to write a struct in .NET - typically for "measure" types - for example, a "time interval" (start/end or start/duration), or "currency value" (decimal+currency code).

Comment: .NET structs come with so many implications beyond "I want the reader of the code to understand that I mean this to be a value, not a behavior".  Handle them with great, great care.

Comment: Hi Marc, I'm curious why you're so adamant? The first sentence describes the context as being to store data. None of the code expresses change of state or behaviour, nor does it seem to need polymorphism or nullability. Aside from boxing costs, isn't using the stack and avoiding GC more efficient?

Comment: No; getting the right behaviour is more efficient. Re performance, oversized structs (too many properties) can *reduce* efficiency due to the number of times they get clopied (every method call, etc). But the bigger issue is losing changes due to value-type semantics.

Comment: Seriously: domain entity objects *even if they just hold data and don't do anything with it* should be classes. Every time. And structs should *unless you really, really know what you are doing* always be immutable - i.e. shouldn't have any setters (or other ways of mutating state).

Comment: As for "adamant" - because I've seen far too many people get tripped up by this... they use the "it only holds data" approach, make it a struct, then wonder why their changes keep getting lost. That might apply to C/C++, but it does *not* apply to C#; struct vs class is very different in C#.

Comment: Thanks, I could argue some of your points, but I can see where you're coming from. Thanks for the taking the time to explain.